# bower error : Cannot read property '_direct' of undefined

Tags: bower

I am trying to uninstall some unused dependencies using bower. But when I execute command :

```
bower uninstall metro-ui-css --save
```

I am getting this error :

```
bower error Cannot read property '_direct' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_direct' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, after having a look around my bower_components director I found that one of the files had the wrong permissions. After I ran:

> sudo rm -r bower_components

then ran

> bower update

this fixed the problem for me

Comment: But this will remove all the bower components? And Will have to install all dependencies again?

Comment: Depends on how your bower.json file is structured for your project. I've got this file under version control, so I can nuke the bower_components directory and then auto-recreate it via bower update